# Stylesheet not linking to flask webpage

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm currently learning Flask (noob question warning) and currently I am having issues getting my CSS to appear. Currently, I have two HTML files (base and index, with index extending base).

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--links the stylesheet to the base template-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Test Head</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Other people that had the same issue as me online were due to not using jinja2 or not placing their css file in a static folder, but I have done both of those things (my main.css file is located in static/css/main.css). As a test, I edited my body styling in css as such:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font: 54px;
}
```

I can tell there's an issue somewhere since the webpage shows the text in sans-serif, when my css sets body text to Georgia.

Comment: You can open your html page and view page source to check if you are getting link to your css file. There might an issue with the cache as well. This will clear the doubt and you will be able to check the link of css file.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha When I view page source, it says that the text is using the sans-serif font family, which is showing that there is surely an issue

Comment: Do you have for that font installed in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, and it was solved by accessing the website via incognito mode on chrome. The issue was probably due to the web browser cache.